# How can I create inline CSS in a WordPress PHP file without referencing to an external CSS file?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to enqueue a string of CSS directly from a Wordpress plugin. I don't want to load it from an external file, and I don't want to debate why this is the write or wrong thing to do, I just want to know if it is possible.

In other words, I know I can do this:

```
wp_register_style('myStyleSheet', 'my-stylesheet.php');
wp_enqueue_style( 'myStyleSheet');
```

But I don't wan't to.

What I want to do is something like this (pseudocode):

```
$number = get_option('some_width')/2;
$css = " .divbox { width: $number; } ";
wp_register_style('myStyleSheet', $css);
wp_enqueue_style( 'myStyleSheet');
```

I read the wp codex for wp_register_style() and it doesn't seem possible. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well that was silly of me. I found the answer a few minutes later. Desperation is a good motivator! :)

The trick is not to use  wp_register_style() and wp_enqueue_style()

Here is what I did:

```
function myStyleSheet() {

  global $value;
  $num = $value/2;

  echo '
       <style type="text/css">
            .divbox { width: '.$num.'; }    
       </style>
    ';
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'myStyleSheet' );
```

Still, maybe there is a better way?